# Python3 asyncio - callback for add_done_callback do not updates self variable in server class

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I have two servers, created with asyncio.start_server:
`asyncio.start_server(self.handle_connection, host = host, port = port)` and running in one loop:

```
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(server1, server2))
loop.run_forever()
```

I'm using asyncio.Queue to communicate between servers. Messages from Server2, added via `queue.put(msg)` successfully receives by `queue.get()` in Server1. I'm running `queue.get()` by `asyncio.ensure_future` and using as callback for
`add_done_callback` method from Server1:

```
def callback(self, future):
    msg = future.result()
    self.msg = msg
```

But this `callback` not working as expected - self.msg do not updates. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATED**
with additional code to show max full example:

```
class Queue(object):

    def __init__(self, loop, maxsize: int):
        self.instance = asyncio.Queue(loop = loop, maxsize = maxsize)

    async def put(self, data):
        await self.instance.put(data)

    async def get(self):
        data = await self.instance.get()
        self.instance.task_done()
        return data

    @staticmethod
    def get_instance():
        return Queue(loop = asyncio.get_event_loop(), maxsize = 10)
```

Server class:

```
    class BaseServer(object):

        def __init__(self, host, port):
            self.instance = asyncio.start_server(self.handle_connection, host = host, port = port)

        async def handle_connection(self, reader: StreamReader, writer: StreamWriter):
            pass

        def get_instance(self):
            return self.instance

        @staticmethod
        def create():
            return BaseServer(None, None)
```

Next I'm running the servers:

```
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(server1.get_instance(), server2.get_instance()))
loop.run_forever()
```

In the `handle_connection` of server2 I'm calling `queue.put(msg)`, in the `handle_connection` of server1 I'm registered `queue.get()` as task:

```
 task_queue = asyncio.ensure_future(queue.get())
 task_queue.add_done_callback(self.process_queue)
```

The `process_queue` method of server1:

```
    def process_queue(self, future):
        msg = future.result()
        self.msg = msg
```

The `handle_connection` method of server1:

```
 async def handle_connection(self, reader: StreamReader, writer: StreamWriter):
     task_queue = asyncio.ensure_future(queue.get())
     task_queue.add_done_callback(self.process_queue)

     while self.msg != SPECIAL_VALUE:
        # doing something
```

Although `task_queue` is done, `self.process_queue` called, `self.msg` never updates.

Comment: Could you print out something to confirm `callback` is executed?

Comment: @Sraw sure.. please see my updated question

Comment: Are your sure `self.process_queue` is called? In my opinion, your program is just blocked by an infinite loop `while self.msg != SPECIAL_VALUE:`. All other codes will never be executed. Could you add a `print("Whatever")` in `process_queue` to prove it is called?

Comment: @Sraw you are right! I moved `task_queue` declaration from `handle_connection` to my run.py script and `print('whatever')` outputs, but `self.msg` still not changed in the `while self.msg != SPECIAL_VALUE:`

Comment: `asyncio` is a single thread structure, your program is just blocked by your infinite loop. You need to change your structure. BTW you should first understand how it works exactly. Basically that is just a syntax sugar of callback-based event loop in a single thread.

Comment: @Sraw can you please give a hint ? What do you mean in "change your structure" ?

Comment: As you can see, now you are checking value in an infinite loop which blocks you totally. You should also make this part asynchronous. That's what I mean "change structure", the structure of your program.

Comment: @Sraw if you can give small code example as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically as you are using asynchronous structure, I think you can directly await the result:

```
async def handle_connection(self, reader: StreamReader, writer: StreamWriter):
    msg = await queue.get()
    process_queue(msg)  # change it to accept real value instead of a future.
    # do something
```